# Transparent Compression for BLOB on mysql

Tags: mysql, compression, mariadb

I'm creating a Table in mysql/mariadb with a BLOB column (innoDB).
Is the the BLOB column transparent compressed or not? Or does I have to manual Compress/Decompress the Data with `COMPRESS(..)`, `UNCOMPRESS(..)`?

(As far as I know postresql has transparent compression on BLOB columns)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL and MariaDB do not transparently compress `BLOBs`.

With `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`, InnoDB *tables* (in MySQL and MariaDB) can be transparently compressed.  This gives about 2x compression, and has various pros and cons.

I generally recommend doing the compression in the client, not with the database's `COMPRESS()`.  This

- Offloads the CPU effort from the database server to the clients.  (It is easier to scale clients than database masters), and
- Cuts down on the network traffic between client and server.

`COMPRESS()`, and its equivalent in various client languages, gives about 3x compression for typical text (code, XML, English, etc).  For images (jpg, etc) and pdfs, etc, you get essentially no compression since they are already compressed.